# Glympse API - Send Glympse Tickets - Feasibility

Tags: android, glympse

I want to integrate Glympse API in my application, where there are two users for my mobile application, using applications separately and if One person wants to see the Real Time location of the Another one, and both of them works on different modules but same application.

Is it feasible with your Glympse API ?

Moreover I am getting Null Pointer while getting Instance from GlympseLiteWrapper when trying to send a Glympse Ticket using the following code

```
**/*Send a Glympse*/**
        GTicketLite ticket = LiteFactory.createTicket(3600000, "Going home!", null);
        // Set flags that adjust the presentation of the Glympse Send Wizard. 
        // These can enable/disable fields in the wizard screen.
        final int WIZARD_FLAGS 
         = LC.SEND_WIZARD_INVITES_EDITABLE
         | LC.SEND_WIZARD_MESSAGE_EDITABLE
         | LC.SEND_WIZARD_DESTINATION_EDITABLE
         | LC.SEND_WIZARD_TIME_EDITABLE;
        // Launches the wizard which will send the Glympse
        GGlympseLite glympse = GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().getGlympse();
        glympse.sendTicket(ticket, WIZARD_FLAGS);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "and both of them works on different modules but same application" ?

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception is most likely because the Glympse platform is not started prior to calling these methods. Please see the sample applications in our Lite SDK for examples on how to handle starting and stopping the platform inside Android's Activity lifecycle methods. Starting the platform in your app should look something like this

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Start up the Glympse API
    GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().start(this);

    // Register this class as a listener for Glympse events
    GlympseLiteWrapper.instance().getGlympse().addListener(this);
}
```

Also make sure you have obtained an API key from our developer site and set it in GlympseLiteWrapper.java.

Your use case definitely sounds like it can make great use of the Glympse API. The Lite SDK only comes with support for viewing Glympses in web browser. The commercial SDK comes with tools for displaying received Glympses inside your own app.

See here for a list of differences between the Lite and Commercial SDK and send us a message if it sounds like you'll need our full SDK: https://developer.glympse.com/comparison